# Addingdependency jars to spark classpath in a standalone mode

Tags: apache-spark, classpath

I m trying to execute my local java program in spark which has dependencies, i tried executing spark submit option as below :

```
spark-submit --class com.cerner.doc.DocumentExtractor  /Users/sp054800/Downloads/Docs_lib_jar/Docs_RestAPI.jar
```

after setting the

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath /Users/sp054800/Downloads/Docs_lib_jar/lib/*
spark.driver.extraLibraryPath /Users/sp054800/Downloads/Docs_lib_jar/lib/*
spark.executor.extraClassPath /Users/sp054800/Downloads/Docs_lib_jar/lib/*
spark.executor.extraLibraryPath /Users/sp054800/Downloads/Docs_lib_jar/lib/*
```

in `spark-defaults.conf`, but still no help could anyone help me to fix this of how do i need to include the jars in spark. I m using spark2.2.0

Comment: Could you elaborate on _"but still no help"_? How do you know that the settings don't work?

Comment: Have you tried the `--jars` option?

Comment: Yeah since i got class not found execption even after adding this..

Comment: I do not want to use --jars option since there are many jars like 20+